# Generating database per tenant using EF C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am building a multi-tenant application using `C# EF Code First approach`.

I am opting for separate DB per tenant. In this regard, when the application loads the tenant can login or register.

This is how registration page looks like.

[image]

On submit, I capture this tenant details in the common DB with name `MyAppDB` & table `tblTenants`

Here Tenant name is unique & on successful submission of the form, I need to create new DB on the same server with Tenant name & generate set of tables for the Models.

This is my model looks like for every Tenant.

```
public class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}
}

public class Sales
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

How do I generate this Models to tables using C# EF Code First approach??

Thanks.

Comment: You can create the [database programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg679221(v=vs.103).aspx). Should you do it is a different question.

Comment: @FilipCordas, Please validate my ans

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have two questions.

1. How do I create a database programmatically on an SQL Server?

   If you don't want any dependencies in your code, you can run run sql commands directly against your sql server:

   ```
   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
   {
         connection.Open();
         var command = connection.CreateCommand();
         command.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE mydb";
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```

   Bam you got your new db, the connection string for your new db will be `"Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"`
2. How do I create tables in the new db using EF code-first?

   You don't necessarily, you let EF deal with this.

   Create your tenantdbcontext class:

   ```
   public class TenantDbContext : DbContext
   {
       public TenantDbContext () : Base("name=yourConnString") { }

       public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Sales> Sales { get; set; }
   }
   ```

In your code when you need to access those tables use

```
TenantDbContext tdc = new TenantDbContext();
tdc.Products.Add(new Product)
```

Your challenege will be in using the appropriate connection strings to appropriate contexts according to which tenant you are working with.

Comment: Please have a look at my ans & validate. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have addressed my requirement currently.

When any new user/tenant submits the form,

1. First, I am inserting user/tenant details into common/master DB
2. Then I create a new DB with Tenant Name on the server.

Submit Action:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTenant(Tenanat tenanat)
    {
        //Master/Common DB
        using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            ctx.Tenanats.Add(tenanat);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tenantContext"].ConnectionString;
            con = con.Replace("tenDbName", tenanat.Name.Trim());

            TenantContext tenantContext = new TenantContext(con,tenanat);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tenanat",tenanat);
    }
```

This is what my TenantContext class looks like which is handling the primary stuff to generate the DB on demand.

```
 public class TenantContext : DbContext
 {
    public TenantContext(string connection, Tenanat tenanat)
        : base(connection)
    {
        //create DB for tenant
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
        //create user for the new Db
        string sql = "CREATE LOGIN \"" + tenanat.Email + "\" WITH PASSWORD = '" + tenanat.Password + "'; USE " + tenanat.Name + "; CREATE USER \"" + tenanat.Email + "\" FOR LOGIN \"" + tenanat.Email + "\" WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;";
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
   }}
```

Please feel free to validate this approach & add suggestions.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If you ask me I would not do this in the constructor. And don't use string concatenation in sql especially without validation this isn't safe from sql injection. Why dose your tenant have password that looks like a user to me. Also don't store passwords in plain text if you can use existing identify systems unless you know security well.

Comment: Something else I think you looked at [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework) post for the answer. They are using DI for tenant into so that is why you have AppTenant in constructor you should use DI too not create with new.

Comment: @FilipCordas, This is just skeleton of the approach. DI & other stuff will be taken care in real app

Comment: If nothing else remove that sql injection part so someone doesn't do a copy paste.